# Tesseract does not work with ubuntu called from within a Java Spring App(can`t find liblept.so.5)

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, tesseract

I'm facing an issue with Tesseract while working on Linux(Ubuntu22.04) and in Docker. I'm using Java Spring Boot. Here are Maven dependencies:

```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
       <version>5.6.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
       <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
       <version>4.6.0-0</version>
     </dependency>
```

And here is the error that occurs:
`Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
2023-09-16T11:45:28.441+03:00 ERROR 11051 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'pixFreeAndSetData': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblept.so.5: undefined symbol: pixFreeAndSetData] with root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'pixFreeAndSetData': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblept.so.5: undefined symbol: pixFreeAndSetData
at com.sun.jna.Function.(Function.java:252) ~[jna-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0 (b0)]
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:620) ~[jna-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0 (b0)]
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:596) ~[jna-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0 (b0)]
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:582) ~[jna-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0 (b0)]`

As I see, it is a regular issue. However, I still can't find a solution.